# UITableView blank slate using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

What's the best approach for creating a blank slate view for a `UITableView` that's visible when the `NSFetchedResultsController` has no objects, and hidden otherwise?

If I add a subview to the `UITableView`, I need to position it to align with the `tableHeaderView` that may change size.
And I'm not sure how to use a `UITableViewCell` as a blank slate without breaking the `NSFetchedResultsController` logic.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can use:

1. If the base class is a `UIViewController`, add your empty message subview behind the table view and set `hidden` to `YES` on the table
2. If you are using `UITableViewController`, you can set the `tableHeaderView` to your empty message view, ensure its height matches the height of the table, and then set `scrollEnabled` to `NO` on the table
3. For either case, you can add a subview to the `UITableView` and use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods (mainly `scrollViewDidScroll:`) to keep the view stationary during scrolling.